# Error while installing node 10 using Homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install node version 10 on Macbook Pro (m1 chip) using below Homebrew command.

```
brew install node@10
```

But getting below error:

```
Error: node@10: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
brew install --build-from-source node@10
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Could anyone please help me in installing node 10 using Homebrew. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

[Brew does not yet provide an ARM version of Node 10](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node@10#default)

Did you try an install from source? `brew install --build-from-source node@10`

You might be able to run X86 command line programs by [creating a Terminal that uses the Rosetta emulation layer](https://osxdaily.com/2020/11/18/how-run-homebrew-x86-terminal-apple-silicon-mac/) but I have not tested this.

> - Locate the Terminal application within the Utilities folder (Finder > Go menu > Utilities)
> - Select Terminal.app and right-click on it, then choose “Duplicate”
> - Rename the duplicated Terminal app something obvious and distinct, like ‘Rosetta Terminal’
> - Now select the freshly renamed ‘Rosetta Terminal’ app and right-click and choose “Get Info” (or hit Command+i)
> - Check the box for “Open using Rosetta”, then close the Get Info window
> - Run the “Rosetta Terminal” as usual, which will fully support Homebrew and other x86 command line apps

Comment: I didn't try this brew install --build-from-source node@10 because there is warning: Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.